# upload_max_filesize error in php.ini

Tags: php.ini

I have a error while uploading my download theme for about a size of 2.3 MB with these error The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. . and when i try to change the value of upload_max_filesize = 10MB from default 2M to all php.ini, php.ini-development and php.ini-production I got same error. I could not upload my downloaded theme while about a size of 2.3 MB. I am using XAMPP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you edited the right php.ini file. Place a php file with `phpinfo()` in you webspace and check the values. There are possibly more than one, for cli and for web or different php versions. 
Also check the `post_max_size` value in your php.ini, when you know it's the correct one. Set it to 10MB as well and try again.

Comment: I added it to my .htaccess file and it worked. php_value upload_max_filesize 3M
php_value post_max_size 3M
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value max_input_time 60. Am I doing this correct?

Comment: It depends on your hosting setup. If php runs as apache module and you have allow_override privileges, it will work. But you can also set php configuration options with the ```ini_set()``` function.

Comment: I used XAMMP and using only my laptop as practice development.